# Runtime Error 429 - ActiveX Component Can't Create Object

Tags: vb6, activex, common-controls

We have a VB6 program being run on Windows 2008 R2 Server. We are getting the error:

> **Runtime Error 429 -ActiveX Component Can't Create Object**

ActiveX component: MSCOMCTL.OCX

The same program is running successfully on another Windows 2008 R2 Server.

Comment: Is MSCOMCTL.OCX registered?

Comment: Yes, it is registered.

Comment: Will it have any dependency on VC++ 2005 Redistributable. I have 64bit installed on my machine but 32bit is not installed. Should I need to try installing VC++ 2005 Redistributable 32bit?

Comment: The issue has been resolved after installing VC++ 2005 Redistributable 32bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved after installing VC++ 2005 Redistributable 32bit.